# Count lines in multiple csv files, skip blank lines

Tags: python, csv, content-length, emptydatatext

I need to get the length of csv files in ('/dir'/) excluding empty rows.
I tried this:

```
import os, csv, itertools, glob

#To filer the empty lines
def filterfalse(predicate, iterable):
    # filterfalse(lambda x: x%2, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8
    if predicate is None:
        predicate = bool
    for x in iterable:
        if not predicate(x):
            yield x

#To read each file in '/dir/', compute the length and write the output 'count.csv'
with open('count.csv', 'w') as out:
     file_list = glob.glob('/dir/*')
     for file_name in file_list:
         with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
              filt_f1 = filterfalse(lambda line: line.startswith('\n'), f)
              count = sum(1 for line in f if (filt_f1))
              out.write('{c} {f}\n'.format(c = count, f = file_name))
```

I get the output I'd like, but unfortunately the length of each file (in '/dir/') includes empty rows.

To see where empty rows are coming from I read `file.csv` as `file.txt` and it looks like this:

```
*text,favorited,favoriteCount,...
"Retweeted user (@user):...
'empty row'
Do Operators...*
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pandas.

```
import pandas

# Reads csv file and converts it to pandas dataframe.
df = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv')

# Removes rows where data is missing.
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Gets length of dataframe and displays it.
df_length = df.count + 1
print('The length of the CSV file is', df_length)
```

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/

Answer (score 1):

Your `filterfalse()` function performs correctly. It's *exactly* the same as the one named [`ifilterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse) in the standard library `itertools` module, so it's unclear why you don't just use that rather than write your own — a major advantage being that it's already been tested and debugged. (Built-ins are often faster, too, since many are written in C.)

The problem is you're not using the [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) properly.

1. Since it returns a [generator object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types), one needs to iterate over the multiple values it will potentially `yield` using code like `for line in filt_f1`.
2. The predicate function argument you give doesn't handle lines that have other leading whitespace characters in them, like spaces and tabs, properly. — so the `lambda` you pass it needs to be modified to handle those cases, too.

The code below has both of these changes made to it.

```
import os, csv, itertools, glob

#To filter the empty lines
def filterfalse(predicate, iterable):
    # filterfalse(lambda x: x%2, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8
    if predicate is None:
        predicate = bool
    for x in iterable:
        if not predicate(x):
            yield x

#To read each file in '/dir/', compute the length and write the output 'count.csv'
with open('count.csv', 'w') as out:
    file_list = glob.glob('/dir/*')
    for file_name in file_list:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            filt_f1 = filterfalse(lambda line: not line.strip(), f)  # CHANGED
            count = sum(1 for line in filt_f1)  # CHANGED
            out.write('{c} {f}\n'.format(c=count, f=file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works partially (i.e.I can still find some blank lines)